# MATLAB: I want to threshold a matrix, based on thresholds in a vector, without a for loop. Possible?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, find

Let us say I have the following:

```
M = randn(10,20);
T = randn(1,20);
```

I would like to threshold each column of `M`, by each entry of `T`. For example, find all indicies of all elements of `M(:,1)` that are greater than `T(1)`. Find all indicies of all elements in `M(:,2)` that are greater than `T(2)`, etc etc.

Of course, I would like to do this without a for-loop. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` like this:

```
I = bsxfun(@gt, M, T);
```

Then `I` will be a logcial matrix of `size(M)` with ones where `M(:,i) > T(i)`.

Comment: Ah, fantastic - I had no idea this existed!! :-)

Comment: Neither did I for a long time.. :)

Comment: `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, `bsxfun`, and `spfun` are all functions that allow you do some pretty interesting operations in lieu of the dreaded for-loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)  to do things like this, but it may not be faster than a for loop (more below on this).

```
result = bsxfun(@gt,M,T)
```

This will do an element wise comparison and return you a logical matrix indicating the relationship governed by the first argument. I have posted code below to show the direct comparison, indicating that it does return what you are looking for.

```
%var declaration
M = randn(10,20);
T = randn(1,20);
% quick method
fastres = bsxfun(@gt,M,T);

% looping method
res = false(size(M));
for i = 1:length(T)
    res(:,i) = M(:,i) > T(i);
end

% check to see if the two matrices are identical
isMatch = all(all(fastres == res))
```

This function is very powerful and can be used to help speed up processes, but keep in mind that it will only speed things up if there is a lot of data. There is a bit of background work that `bsxfun` must do, which can actually cause it to be slower.

I would only recommend using it if you have several thousand data points. Otherwise, the traditional for-loop will actually be faster. Try it out for yourself by changing the size of the `M` and `T` variables.

Comment: No problem. It is all about learning, which makes for such an appropriate user name :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate the threshold vector and use matrix comparison:

```
s=size(M);
T2=repmat(T, s(1), 1);
M(M<T2)=0;
Indexes=find(M);
```